# jquery date range: input text box value is changed to null if date is not selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, c#-4.0, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have enabled jquery date range picker on two input boxes to select start date & end date, by default value of startDateInput=Start Date and endDateInput=End Date. But when start input box is clicked and start date is selected, value written in endDateInput which is equal to End Date is changed to null. Script which i am using is below:

startDate(Name of input box for selecting Start Date)
endDate(Name of input box for selecting End Date)

```
$(function () {
    $("#startDate").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: new Date(2012, 11 - 1, 27),
        maxDate: -1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#endDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#endDate").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: new Date(2012, 11 - 1, 28),
        maxDate: -1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#startDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were talking about water marks, then you can try this:

```
$(function () {
        $("#startDate").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            minDate: new Date(2012, 11 - 1, 27),
            maxDate: -1,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                if ($("#endDate").val() != 'End Date') {
                    $("#endDate").datepicker("setDate", selectedDate);
                }
            }
        });
        $("#endDate").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            minDate: new Date(2012, 11 - 1, 28),
            maxDate: -1,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                if ($("startDate").val() != 'Start Date') {
                    $("#startDate").datepicker("setDate", selectedDate);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the `selectedDate` into `Date` object before assigning to `datepicker` in the `onClose` function.

Modify your code as below.

```
$(function () {
    $("#startDate").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: new Date(2012, 11 - 1, 27),
        maxDate: -1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#endDate").datepicker("option", "minDate",new Date(selectedDate));
        }
    });
    $("#endDate").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: new Date(2012, 11 - 1, 28),
        maxDate: -1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#startDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", new Date(selectedDate));
        }
    });
});
```

Refer : 
Check for [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BEEbv/)

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply!! but i have a text value in my input boxes Start Date and End Date, when start Date is selected, text value in endDate input box is set to null

Answer (score 0):

The way date is set is not correct.

Replace:

```
$("#endDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
```

With:

```
 $("#endDate").datepicker("setDate", selectedDate);
```

and also replace:

```
$("#startDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
```

with:

```
$("#startDate").datepicker("setDate", selectedDate);
```

I hope it will help.